# NextAuth + AWS Cognito - message: 'nonce mismatch, expected undefined, got:

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, next.js, amazon-cognito, next-auth

I'm using `nextjs 12.1.6`, `nextauth ^4.5.0`, `cognito` to create social sign ins. After successful sign in on the cognito `Hosted UI`, I get redirected to my nextjs app with this error in the url `api/auth/signin?error=OAuthCallback`. I'm not sure what the problem is. Here is the log I get:[image]

here's the nextjs app:
[image]

My cognito callbacks:
[image]

My nextauth config :[image]

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Related GH discussion: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/3551.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get this to work by using the following code:

```
 providers: [
    CognitoProvider({
      clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.COGNITO_ISSUER,
      checks: ['nonce']
    })
]
```

This is with:

```
    "next": "^14.1.4",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.5",
```