# how to completely destroy client side session with NextAuth.js & AWS Cognito

Tags: authentication, next.js, amazon-cognito, next-auth

i am using Next.js with NextAuth.js with a amazon cognito setup and my issue is that when i click on signin link right after logging out, my user gets signed in directly without getting asked for credentials.

my [...nextauth].ts looks like this:

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CognitoProvider from 'next-auth/providers/cognito';

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CognitoProvider({
      clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID || '',
      clientSecret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET || '',
      issuer: process.env.COGNITO_ISSUER_URL,
    }),
  ],
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? true : false,
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

For authentication i use the Next helper methods signIn and signOut:

```js
interface HomeProps {
  appTitle: string;
}

const Home: NextPage<HomeProps> = ({ appTitle }) => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  if (status === 'authenticated') {
    return (
      <>
        <Head>
          <title>{appTitle}</title>
        </Head>
        <p>Signed in as {session.user?.email}</p>
        <Link href="/">
          <a
            onClick={() => {
              signOut();
            }}
          >
            Log out
          </a>
        </Link>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{appTitle}</title>
      </Head>
      <Link href="/">
        <a
          onClick={(event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            signIn('cognito', {
              callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
            });
          }}
        >
          Sign In
        </a>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I assume that the client keeps some information about the previous signed in user after logout but i don't know which data and where it is located.

I would like to completely delete all information after logout so that when clicking on signin the user always gets asked for credentials. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been facing this same issue and tracked back why thats happening. When the helper signIn method is invoked it redirects us to the hosted UI provided by cognito which is a different domain website from your own app. And that particular domain has its own local storage and session information. Cognito utilise that session credentials and logs you in without prompting for new username and password.

For now, I couldn't find a proper solution for my use case as for security, you're not allowed to edit (or delete) a cookie on another site. So I am just providing these information for tracking back the how the client side storing that data.

One solution is invoking the logout endpoint provided [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html). On logout you can make a callback for that url which will clear the credential from that cognito domain each time you signout

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you registered `Allowed sign-out URLs`  in Hosted UI of AppClient in Cognito  eg : `http://localhost:3000/login`

Then

```
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";

export default function useLogout() {
  const handleLogout = async function () {
    const logoutCognitoUrl = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_COGNITO_DOMAIN}/logout?client_id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID}&logout_uri=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL}/login&redirect_uri=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL}/login&response_type=code`;
    return signOut({
      callbackUrl: logoutCognitoUrl,
    });
  };

  return {
    handleLogout,
  };
}
```

Logout URL sample:
`https://your-pool-id.auth.ap-southeast-1.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=your_client_id24&logout_uri=http://localhost:3000/login&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/login&response_type=code`

This is a copy ready version of @FaisalHossain

Answer (score 2):

There are [workarounds](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/3938) that involve overriding the built in SignOut methods, but obviously it would be ideal if this can be added into nextauth as a feature.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by [@vanduc1102](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77076926/12789671) is almost perfect. To sign out user we need to redirect to the logout Cognito url using the **router** (or something else).

The **callbackUrl** from **signOut** method is a URL which will redirect user after sign in. This URL needs to be absolute URL at the same host name or relative ([Next Auth docs about callBackUrl and signOut](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#signout)).

Hence we need to use **signOut({ redirect: false })** so the page will not be reloaded and then we need to redirect to Cognito sign out URL using router =>
**router.push(logoutCognitoUrl)**.

```js
"use client";
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export function SingOutButton() {
    const router = useRouter();

    const logoutCognitoUrl = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_COGNITO_DOMAIN}/logout?client_id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID}&logout_uri=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL}/login&redirect_uri=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL}/login&response_type=code`;

    return (
        <button
            onClick={() =>
                signOut({ redirect: false }).then(() =>
                    router.push(logoutCognitoUrl),
                )
            }
        >
            Sign out
        </button>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hint by @faisal-hussain helped me resolve this issue, posting it here in case other users are affected as well.

First, I declared the Cognito domain as a public environment variable (this is the one with syntax https://{prefix}.{region}.amazoncognito.com on top of the "App Integration" tab of User pool). I also had to declare the Client ID as a public environment variable, since the logout is being triggered by a client component.

Then, on sign out, I added the following code:

```
await signOut();
let url = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COGNITO_DOMAIN}/logout?client_id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID}&logout_uri=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN}&redirect_uri=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN}&response_type=code`;
await router.push(url);
```

This clears out both the Google provider as well as email/password correctly, returning me to home page after logging out the user, and shows the Cognito UI when I attempt to sign in.

My Cognito provider is configured as follows (wasted a lot of time tracking down the 'nonce' issue but that's a [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72651696/nextauth-aws-cognito-message-nonce-mismatch-expected-undefined-got) issue).

```
providers: [
    CognitoProvider({
      clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.COGNITO_ISSUER,
      checks: ['nonce']
    })
]
```